# Mathematica 12.0 returning a imaginary value for a real-valued improper integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier and persisting through 12.3.1**

---

When I use Mathematica to evaluate this integral

```
Integrate[(1 - Cos[x])/( 2 - Cos[x] - Cos[y]), {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```

it returns `8I*Pi*Log[2]`, which is obviously wrong.
If I calculate it as an iterated integral,

```
Integrate[Integrate[(1 - Cos[x])/(2 - Cos[x] - Cos[y]), {y, -Pi, Pi}], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

Mathematica gives `2Pi^2`, which is correct.
Can anybody give an explanation?

Comment: This doesn't explain anything but because of the symmetry `4 Integrate[(1 - Cos[x])/(2 - Cos[x] - Cos[y]), {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]` gives $2\pi^2$.

Comment: Adding `Assumptions -> {x, y} \[Element] Reals` gives correct result.

Comment: This is an improper double integral. There is a singularity at the origin :`MaxLimit[(1 - Cos[x])/(2 - Cos[x] - Cos[y]), {x, y} -> {0, 0}]` results in `Infinity`. The existence of the improper integral is unclear to me.

Comment: `NIntegrate[(1 - Cos[x])/(2 - Cos[x] - Cos[y]), {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, 
  Pi}, Exclusions -> (x^2 + y^2 == 0)]` produces `19.7392`, confirming `2*Pi^2`.

Comment: Please report this to Support. Note that swapping the order of integration gives a different, yet also incorrect, answer.